# Как работает под капотом распаковка в Python (*)?

Tags: python

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как работает распаковка(*) под капотом, на примере обычного генераторного выражения.

```
gen = (num for num in range(10))


print(*gen)
```

Comment: Генерируются элементы, потом подставляются в параметры функции.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Слева обычный вызов `f` с тремя аргументами, справа вызов с помощью `*`. Оба варианта делают одно и тоже:

> ```
> import dis                             import dis
>
>
> def f(a, b, c):                        def f(a, b, c):
>     return a + b + c                       return a + b + c
>
>
> def driver():                          def driver():
>     g = (v for v in range(3))              g = (v for v in range(3))
>     a, b, c = g
>     return f(a, b, c)                      return f(*g)
>
>
> dis.dis(driver)                        dis.dis(driver)
> ```

Кусок исполнимого кода. Слева прямолинейный код: функция и аргументы кладутся на стек, `CALL 3` выполняет функцию с тремя аргументами. Справа на стек помещается функция `f` и генератор `g` и вызывается `CALL_FUNCTION_EX 0`. Что происходит внутри пока не ясно:

> ```
> ...                                    ...
> LOAD_FAST         0 (g)
> UNPACK_SEQUENCE   3
> STORE_FAST        1 (a)
> STORE_FAST        2 (b)
> STORE_FAST        3 (c)
>
> LOAD_GLOBAL       3 (NULL + f)         LOAD_GLOBAL       1 (f)
> LOAD_FAST         1 (a)                LOAD_FAST         0 (g)
> LOAD_FAST         2 (b)
> LOAD_FAST         3 (c)                CALL_FUNCTION_EX  0
> CALL              3
> RETURN_VALUE                           RETURN_VALUE
> ```

Инструкция `CALL_FUNCTION_EX` реализована в [3.12/Python/bytecodes.c#L3194-L3260](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Python/bytecodes.c#L3194-L3260).

Если переданный объект не кортеж (`!PyTuple_CheckExact(callargs)`), из него строят кортеж (`PyObject *tuple = PySequence_Tuple(callargs);`): [3.12/Python/bytecodes.c#L3198-L3207](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Python/bytecodes.c#L3198-L3207).

Затем этот кортеж передаётся в вызов функции (`result = PyObject_Call(func, callargs, kwargs);`): [3.12/Python/bytecodes.c#L3219](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Python/bytecodes.c#L3219) и [3.12/Python/bytecodes.c#L3254](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Python/bytecodes.c#L3254).

Если вы передаёте генератор в вызов функции со звёздочкой, все значения из генератора извлекаются и помещаются в кортеж. Затем вызывается функция с кортежем вместо аргументов. Вызов `f(*g)` равносилен чему-то вроде:

```
if isinstance(g, tuple):
    f(*g)         # не приводит к накладным расходам
else:
    t = tuple(g)  # все накладные расходы тут
    f(*t)         # не приводит к накладным расходам
```

Обычно генераторы используются чтобы не расходовать попусту память: вычисления с генераторами ленивые - следующий элемент будет вычислен только тогда когда он будет нужен. По этой причине бесконечные генераторы нормальный и удобный вариант.

Но нотация `*` - жадная. На практике это означает что для вызова требуется память пропорциональная числу элементов в генераторе. Также надо подождать пока генератор отработает. То есть, если генератор медленный, вызов функции будет отложен до конца его работы. А если генератор бесконечный, то функция никогда не будет вызвана, а дело закончится исчерпанием памяти.

Вот так работает всегда и быстро:

```
for v in g:
    print(v)
```

Вот так работает не всегда и не сразу видны результаты:

```
print(*g, sep='\n')
```

Хотя и кажется что это один и тот же код (почти один и тот же).

**P.S.** Ещё немного ассемблера. Что будет если в функции совмещены позиционные параметры и `*`?

```
import dis


def f(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c


def driver():
    g = (v for v in range(3))
    a = next(g)
    return f(a, *g)


dis.dis(driver)
```

Всё ещё усложнилось: аргументы складываются в список, результаты из генератора добавляются в него же, список копируется в кортеж, кортеж передаётся в вызов функции:

> ```
>  LOAD_GLOBAL       3 (NULL + next)
>  LOAD_FAST         0 (g)
>  CALL              1
>  STORE_FAST        1 (a)
>
>  LOAD_GLOBAL       5 (NULL + f)
>  LOAD_FAST         1 (a)
>  BUILD_LIST        1
>  LOAD_FAST         0 (g)
>  LIST_EXTEND       1
>  CALL_INTRINSIC_1  6 (INTRINSIC_LIST_TO_TUPLE)
>  CALL_FUNCTION_EX  0
>  RETURN_VALUE
> ```

Всякое удобство имеет свою цену. Если вы знаете что генератор может быть велик (очень велик) избегайте `*`.

Answer (score 2):

Всё проще, чем кажется.

*args и **kwargs - это способы передачи переменного количества аргументов в функцию. Другими словами, они "распаковывают" значения из массива/словаря/множества и т.п. и передают эти значения в функцию.

Пример использования `*args`:

```py
def test(a,b): # Принимаем параметры a и b
    print(a + b) # Выводим их сложение

array = [1,2] # Создаём массив из двух чисел

test(*array) # Вывод: 3
```

При записи `*array` значения для функции были преобразованы в `test(1,2)`

Пример использования `**kwargs`:

```py
def test(a,b): # Принимаем параметры a и b
    print(a + b) # Выводим их сложение

dct = {'a':1,'b':2} # Создаём словарь и записываем ключ-значение
test(**dct) # Вывод: 3
```

При записи `**dct` значения для функции были преобразованы в `test(a=1,b=2)`

Таким же образом можно преобразовать данные в обратном направлении:

```py
def test1(*var): # Принимаем параметры в виде множества
    print(var)
 
test1(1,2,3) # Вывод: (1, 2, 3)

def test2(**var): # Принимаем параметры в виде словаря
    print(var)

test2(a=1,b=2) # Вывод: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Как работает *args и **kwargs мне понятно, мне не понятно, что 'вшито' в  звездочку *, как она делает распаковку, так сказать, на физическом уровне. Как она берет, например, генератор и последовательно распаковывает один за другим элементы.